# DDD, Entity Framework and Entity Mapping

Tags: c#, entity-framework, domain-driven-design

I'm currently working on an architecture and patterns for our next project. I'm considering using DDD, but since the project will be of medium scale, I'm trying to make it as simple as possible from the perspective of code duplication and overall maintenance.

The layers look as follows, basically each layer is a separate assembly:

```
DB -> Domain -> Application -> Web API -> Clients
```

For DB access I'm using EF Core 1.0.

Here is my current design (simplified) of the classes in data and domain layers and which I'm not very happy with.

Domain:

```
class Task
{
  private int State { get; set; }
  private string Description { get; set; }
  private int CreatedById { get; set; }            
}
```

Data (EF):

```
class TaskData
{
  public int State { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public int CreatedById { get; set; }
  public User CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Ideally I would like to use my domain entity directly with the ORM, but the Task and TaskData are not identical. In Task entity I don't need the navigation property CreatedBy, I'm fine with just an Id, so I don't want to pollute the domain with stuff it doesn't care about.

In data model I'm using the navigation property for some reports, so this join is useful in some cases.

As you can see, if I can't map domain entities directly, I have to do some mapping in the data layer. To be more specific, in the repository via. manual mapper class. Because my domain entity has no public getters and setters, I can't map TaskData to Task entity on a property basis.

This leads me to memento pattern, so I create new class, which seems to be just plain DTO:

```
class TaskSnapshot
{
  public int State { get; set; }
  public string Description { get; set; }
  public int CreatedById { get; set; }
}
```

And my original Task entity looks now like:

```
class Task
{
  ...           
  public Task(TaskSnapshot snapshot)
  {
    this.State = snapshot.State;
    this.Description = snapshot.Description;
    this.CreateById = snapshot.CreatedById;
  }

  public TaskSnapshot ToSnapshot()
  {
    return new TaskSnapshot() 
    {
      State = this.State, 
      Description = this.Description, 
      CreatedBy = this.CreatedBy };
  }
}
```

As you can see, it takes three classes with different purpose, but very similar content to create and maintain. And it's just data and domain layers. The "duplication" continues in other layers too.

Now when I decide to add a new field, I need to remember all the places where to add it and also correctly assign. I'm afraid this will often lead to bugs, because someone from the team just forgets to update all the code.

What I could do:

1. Make getters and setters public on the domain entities, so I wouldn't need Snapshots. -> **Definitely no!**
2. Add unnecessary properties (CreatedBy navigation) to the Task entity and use it directly with ORM. -> **I would rather not.**
3. Transform Snapshot classes to data model and use them with ORM. -> I probably wouldn't mind navigation properties there, but it would mean that data model is part of the domain assembly. -> **I don't know, I don't like it.**

Is there a recommendation how could I effectively reduce number of classes or concentrate **ALL** the assignments (mapping) to one place/mapper class without compromising domain?

Thank you.

Comment: Just a question - why not use code first? This way you map database to your domain layer directly.

Comment: I'm using code first, but in my data model I need to define navigation properties, which I don't need in the domain entity. So the two models are not identical.

Comment: Here there is a couple of strategies: vaughnvernon.co/?p=879

Comment: "In data model I'm using the navigation property for some reports, so this join is useful in some cases" - I think moving reports into a different Bounded Context might make things easier. This means that your Task entity will be same as TaskData. Next if you make the Task entity property getters public and setters private, you can use Task entity as your EF Persistence entity as well. Take a look @ http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/entity-framework-private-constructors-and-private-setters/

Comment: @TomShane Why you dont want to threat ORM object as Domain object? It will make your life much more easier. Also to make your ORM/Domain model "rich" you can use extension methods in you business Layer.

Comment: @Maris Since EF Core 1.0 the framework progressed decently, and many things can be now hidden from domain objects and mapping is done via fluent API. So yes, I'm able to use ORM objects as my domain objects and have them sufficiently encapsulated.

Comment: @TomShane so you got an answer on your first question? The answer on a second question would be - "Use automapper" to map domain objects into DTOs. If you need an example of it's usage - let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment below your question, the first question I would ask is: why don't you want navigation properties in the domain model? As you see it complicates the mapping, but to what concrete advantage?

Also take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355377/what-is-the-best-practice-to-deal-with-navigation-properties-when-using-dto-and), where is stated: "Navigation through association properties is a key concept in DDD."

So to me, sounds like you can keep things really simple by allowing navigation properties in your domain model - like CreatedBy, why should it not be a core concept in your domain? Of course, you would want to disable lazy loading and only load navigation properties if requested explicitly.

Comment: Task domain entity will never interact with the CreatedBy reference. And it is only one of the many properties of this type in the entity. My primary goal is to have domain model as clean as possible, with only things it really needs. I don't want to load these references when loading the entity root (only when generating reports). I don't like the inconsistency that sometimes it will be null and sometimes it will be loaded without exact reason the entity would understand.

Comment: You don't have to load it, as I said, it's loaded only explicitly if needed. A reference that is null, why would that pollute your domain? Other than 'clean as possible', do you have other arguments/advantages? I think you are being extremely purist here, but this often leads to even more problems and complexity by trying to solve something that is not really a problem. Anyway, let us know what solution you go for :)

Comment: I don't mean to be fanatic about the domain cleanness and I'm ready to make some compromises, but I don't want to do it right from the start without carefully assessing other possibilities. Other thing is, I wanted to use EF Core for persistence, but it currently doesn't support value objects very well. The thing is whether to use EF Core and be ready for mapping across the layers (which I wanted to avoid) or use something like NHibernate, which I have no experience with. Those decisions.. :)

Comment: Ok, thinking about it is definitely a good thing, and in the end I'm sure you'll make the right decision :)